# c# - solving complexed ODE set

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, numerical-methods, ode

**Introduction**
Some sets od ODE can't be solved analytically. In this case there are plenty of well-know methods, especially in typical scientific software like MATLAB. As long as you stay with it, all is fine. But the problem starts if you try to port this functionality to other environment. In my case I need it in C#.

**Some details**
Of course, there are some C# libs for ODE's but in most cases (at least in this which i'm familiar with), there are quite limited. Let's look at OSLO library, here's an example query:

```
var sol = Ode.RK547M(0, new Vector(5.0, 1.0),
(t, x) => new Vector(
x[0] - x[0] * x[1],
-x[1] + x[0] * x[1]));
```

As you can see, it doesn't allow to provide any additional support non-OD equations, nor embedded algorithms. It's a bit to limited if we for example have to solve setup like this:

```
a=x*2+7
b=y*x+3
c- need to be calculated with external algorithm basing and "b" and "x"
dx/dt=x - xy + a + c
dx/dt=-y +xy + b
```

In this case presented above lib seems to be not efficient. In C++ I use odeint library by boost. I can define a struct like this:

```
struct solveODE
{
    void operator()( const vector_type &y , vector_type &ODE , const double t )
    {
        double x=y[0];
        double y=y[1];
        a=x*2+7;
        b=y*x+3;
        additional_solve(b, x);
        ODE[0]=x - xy + a + c;
        ODE[1]=-y +xy + b;
        }
};
```

And call it like this:

```
integrate_const(make_dense_output<stepper_type>( 1E-12, 1E-6 ),
                    solveODE(),
                    y, 0.0, t_end, dt ,
                    std::bind(&calc::printResults , std::ref(*this) , pl::_1 , pl::_2));
```

**The problem**

The question is which library for C# will me provide this functionality, **in addition with solving stiff ode sets**? The performance is quite important as ode set may contain 25+ equations + a lot of support algebraic equations. To be more specific - I can't calculate even analytic Jacobian as it will be not constant in time, so the selection of potential solvers is limited.

Comment: Why don't you roll your own Runge-Kutta solver ?

Comment: You mean to build algorithm from scratches? Including solving, refining data to defined steps etc.? It seems a bit like reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You'll probably get faster to the dream tool this way.

Comment: You can use your C++ libs from C#. To do that you need to export your C++ functionality in a DLL with a plain C interface (not C++). From C# you can call the DLL code using pinvoke: https://pinvoke.net

Comment: The `(t, x) => new Vector(` lambda construction is just the ad-hoc definition of a function. You should be able to pass an ordinary function reference in its place.

Comment: @LutzL - can you explain how to do this? As far as I understand the syntax, every lane (separated with coma) must be a right side of an ODE. How to pass algebraic equations or function reference in this case? I can't find right place to insert it.

Comment: Define a function with the signature `Vector odefunc(double, Vector)` and use `(t,y)=>odefunc(t,y)` at that place, but probably just passing the function pointer `odefunc` could work. There might be differences in scoping, access to instance variables etc. for the two call variants, when in doubt, stay with the first.

Comment: Reading the source, the expected parameter is a delegate of type `Func<double,Vector,Vector>`, which needs an explicit construction as such or still the first variant.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused how to do this... I'm not very experienced in C#. Can you provide me with code snippet, basing for example on "struct solveODE" which I presented above? It will be much easier to understand your idea this way. You can post it as Answer, so I can mark it if it will be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
var sol = Ode.RK547M(0, new Vector(5.0, 1.0),
    (t, u) => {
        double x=u[0], y=u[1];
        double a=x*2+7, b=y*x+3;
        double c = additional_solve(b, x);
        return new Vector(
            x - x*y + a + c,
            -y +x*y + b
        );
     });
```

as the long form of a lambda delegate definition, that is, using that `x => x*x` is short for `x => { return x*x; }` which is short for `delegate(x) { return x*x; }` and so on.

Comment: It works, what clearly prove I have to learn a lot about lambda expressions. However it seems like using Ode.GearBDF may be better for stiff ODE sets (more test needed to say it for sure). It's not a problem, as the syntax is the same. I hope this information will be useful for others, like it was for me.