# Solving a system of ordinary differential equations using Math.Net Numerics

Tags: c#, .net, mathnet-numerics

I am trying to solve a system of ordinary differential equations using Math.Net Numerics. It is not the mathematics I am having trouble with. The system I want to solve is:

```
x'(t)=x(t)+2y(t)+2t

y'(t)=3x(t)+2y(t)-4t

x(0)=-7/4, y(0)=55/8
```

I want to solve this system using the fourth order Runge Kutta ODE solver for the system here:
https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.OdeSolvers/RungeKutta.htm

The first parameter it takes in is

```
Vector<T>y0
```

What I am having trouble with is when I click on the link for the `vector<T>`I do not find the basic information. So I am having trouble with understanding this class. Do you understand it and how to use it?

The next parameters are ok until I come to the last one: `Func<double, Vector<double>, Vector<double>>`, since I do not understand the vector class I do not understand how to make this. Do you see how to create this Func?

The last thing I am having trouble with is the return type. It says that it returns a `Vector'1[]`. But what is this? I can't find any documentation for it.

Can you please help me? Maybe someone can show how to solve the equation?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609747/3088138 for using a better solver of a different "library" (with an appropriately advanced interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it. Thanks to Tom W for his help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.OdeSolvers;

namespace Sys
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N = 1000000;
            Vector<double> y0 = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(new[] { -7.0 / 4.0, 55.0 / 8.0 });
            Func<double, Vector<double>, Vector<double>> der = DerivativeMaker();

            Vector<double>[] res = RungeKutta.FourthOrder(y0, 0, 10, N, der);

            double[] x = new double[N];
            double[] y = new double[N];
            for (int i=0; i <N; i++)
            {
                double[] temp = res[i].ToArray();
                x[i] = temp[0];
                y[i] = temp[1];
            }

            //Test
            Console.WriteLine(y[N / 10]); // gives 164,537981852489
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Exp(-1) + 3 * Math.Exp(4) - 5.0 / 2 + 23.0 / 8); //gives 164,537329540604, which is y(1)


            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        static Func<double, Vector<double>, Vector<double>> DerivativeMaker()
        {
            return (t, Z) =>
            {
                double[] A = Z.ToArray();
                double x = A[0];
                double y = A[1];

                return Vector<double>.Build.Dense(new[] { x + 2 * y + 2 * t, 3 * x + 2 * y - 4 * t });

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What the MathNet.Numerics type documentation seems to be missing is information on how to create Vectors, however this is explained in the documentation [kindly linked by Frank Modica:](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html).

To create a `Vector<int>`, write something like:

`var vector = Vector<int>.Build.Dense(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });`

This uses one of the initialisation functions which it appears there are many different types of.

`Vector<T>` is a [generic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/), which means that its members are declared to have a specific type, but this can be any type which satisfies its type constraints. This example is required to explicitly declare the generic type instantiation to be `Vector<int>` with the angle-bracket notation, but in some cases the type can also be inferred by the compiler from the types of the arguments (e.g. the equivalent `CreateVector.Dense(new[] {1, 2, 3})` will infer `T` is `int` from the array type)).

The other thing you'll need to know that's not explained here is how to prepare a [`Func<T1, T2, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=net-7.0). The library documentation also won't explain this because it's another core C# concept. This is called a delegate, and one way to prepare a delegate is an [anonymous function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

To pass an anonymous function to the solver, write something like:

`var result = SecondOrder(y0, start, end, N, (someValue, someVector) => { /* some operation on someValue and someVector which returns a new Vector<T>*/ });`

I'm not familiar with Runge-Kutta so I have no idea what the implementation of your anonymous method should look like, but I've annotated it with a comment.

The expression:

`(someValue, someVector) => { return answer; }` is a Lambda Expression, which is understood by the compiler to match the expected `Func<double, Vector<double>, Vector<double>>` delegate type: it declares a function which takes a double and a vector, and returns a vector.

Finally, the syntax `Vector'1[]` is understandably confusing - this appears to be a problem with the formatting of the documentation. This is a short-hand for a generic type with one type parameter. It should really read `Vector<T>[]`, meaning an array of generic vectors of the same type as the input.

Comment: Nice answer. There are also convenience functions for common types of vectors: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html

Comment: @FrankModica it also unfortunately appears to be wrong; `Vector<T>` is abstract and cannot be constructed. I wrote this before trying out the library myself.

Comment: Thank you. If I let [x,y] denote vector notation, what I want for the anonymous type is:(t, [x,y]) => [x+2y+2t,3x+2y-4t], do you see how to do this?

Comment: @user394334 sorry, I don't know how this library represents a system of equations so I wouldn't know how to construct that function. Can you create a clearly-wrong but syntactically valid placeholder to prove that it compiles and runs?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what that means.

Comment: I mean, provide an anonymous function that returns any vector, knowing that isn't a valid representation of an ODE, and see what the code does when it runs. This is what I'd do as a first step in guessing what the library expects. I've been doing some googling and I haven't found anything so far explaining how this library expects an ODE system to be expressed.