# Can anybody know Runge Kutta implementation for a function with 5 variables?

Tags: c#, function, ode, runge-kutta

I need to solve a differential equation in c# for a function with 5 variables: f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5). As far as I know doesn't exist any library in c# for ODE, so I've started to implement the Runge Kutta but I can't find any formulas for more than 3 variables.My code, looks like this: This is my first function, which has 5 variables. fmin, fmax, fd are other functions which I have implemented.

```
public double f1(double HR, double lambda, double v, double t, double HR0)
        {
            return fmin(HR, lambda) * fmax(HR, lambda) * fd(HR, lambda, v, t, HR0);
        }
```

I have another function:

```
public double f2(double t)
        {
            return 2*t+3;
        }
```

And these two functions make an ODE system. I wrote a method, which needs to solve this system, named solve(), but I can't implement it for 5 variables. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you please post your code and research so it's easy to help you?

Comment: There is the OSLO library as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609747/3088138 that should be sufficient for most purposes. There is no conceptual difference in solving a system of 2, 5 or 500 variables, if you use a vector-oriented approach.

Comment: You could also look at the several implementation of the RK4 method in C and C++ here, some of them are in the "Related" list on the right.